# layout taking time to appear

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building an android application that has 3 different layouts (A->B->C).
When i move from layout A to layout B, it takes around 3-4 seconds to load the layout B.
My B layout contains 7-8 edit texts, 2 list views, and some other widgets.

I am using shared preferences and also using http request in async task.

Although i am creating my list view items from my previous activity's static array list.

Also, my list view that is being created, takes 3 seconds to appear.
Most of my layout items have Visibility="gone".

I copied most of my code from onCreate to onStart method,but there was no difference.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contact_information);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    initialization();
    context = this;
    view = this.getCurrentFocus();

    session = new SessionManager(context);
    saveLocation = new SaveLocation(context);
    dbh_address = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
    navdp = (screenWidth * 29) / 1000;

    htc = new HttpConnectionRecycler(context, phoneProgress, null, session);
    htc.response = this;
    addressTags = new ArrayList<>();
```

}

Comment: Share some code if you can please

Comment: you might be updating your layout in onpostexecute() of async task so it will run only after the doinbackground() have completed

Comment: Please put your code.

Comment: use `AsyncTaskLoader` instead of of `AsyncTask`: it should make your code much simpler

Comment: Everything else i shifted in onResume(). Still not loading quickly.